# Magento - how to JOIN invoice items in magento invoice grid

Tags: mysql, magento

Anyone could help me joining invoice items (or ordered items) in the sales invoice grid?

I want to get the sku(s) from invoice.

```
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass())
    ->addAttributeToSelect('tax_amount')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('increment_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('grand_total')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('shipping_amount')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('subtotal')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('state')
    ->join('order', 'main_table.order_id=order.entity_id', array('shipping_address_id','shipping_method'))
    ->join('order_address', 'order.billing_address_id=order_address.entity_id', array('billing_firstname'=>'firstname','billing_lastname'=>'lastname','email','region','postcode','street','city','telephone','company','pfpj_cui','pfpj_reg_com','pfpj_banca','pfpj_iban'))
    ->join('shipment_track', 'main_table.order_id=shipment_track.order_id', 'track_number')
```

and this is what I have tried, but it is not working...

```
    ->join('invoice_item', 'main_table.entity_id=invoice_item.parent_id', 'sku');
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to explicit the resource model with grouped notation like `sales/order_invoice_collection` instead of `$this->_getCollectionClass()`? If you do this and after you print the query with `$collection->getSelect()` it seems to be fine:

```
SELECT `main_table`.`tax_amount`, `main_table`.`increment_id`,
`main_table`.`created_at`, `main_table`.`entity_id`, `main_table`.`grand_total`,
`main_table`.`shipping_amount`, `main_table`.`subtotal`, `main_table`.`state`,
`order`.`shipping_address_id`, `order`.`shipping_method`, `order_address`.`firstname`
AS `billing_firstname`, `order_address`.`lastname` AS `billing_lastname`,
`shipment_track`.`track_number`, `invoice_item`.`sku` FROM `sales_flat_invoice` AS
`main_table`
INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `order` ON main_table.order_id=order.entity_id
INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `order_address` ON
order.billing_address_id=order_address.entity_id
INNER JOIN `sales_flat_shipment_track` AS `shipment_track` ON
main_table.order_id=shipment_track.order_id
INNER JOIN `sales_flat_invoice_item` AS `invoice_item` ON
main_table.entity_id=invoice_item.parent_id
```

as you can see you have `invoice_item.sku` in the `SELECT` statement